How to put bar series to left instead of centering them?
I put bars with fixed width and fixed gap.
but How can I align them to left? like the following image.
option = {
  xAxis: {
    type: 'category',
    data: ['Mon', 'Tue'],
  },
  yAxis: {
    type: 'value'
  },
  series: [
    {
      data: [120, 200],
      type: 'bar',
      barWidth: 20,
      barGap: 30,
      barCategoryGap: 30,
      align: 'left'
    }
  ]
};



If your xAxis values do not matter you can use type: 'value' together with the max property and position your bars based on that.
Example:
option = {
  xAxis: {
    type: 'value',
    max: 10,
    axisTick: { show: false },
    axisLabel: { show: false }
  },
  yAxis: {
    type: 'value'
  },
  series: [
    {
      type: 'bar',
      barWidth: 20,
      data: [[1, 120], [2, 200]],
    }
  ]
};

